# Bootstrap 5 Input Text-Align right

Tags: javascript, css, input, text-align, bootstrap-5

I want to display the values of my inputs aligned to the right. How can I do that?

[You can see in the image what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45djU.png)

My code is as follows:

```
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 8px 18px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control float-end" id="orden${count}" value="${c}">
</td>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `text-end` class...

```
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 8px 18px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control float-end text-end" id="orden${count}" value="${c}">
</td>
```