# How can I right align column with text and input?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

I am upgrading a project using bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 5.  I have columns with text and input and I need to align them to the right side of the column. I am not finding the right way in Bootstrap 5 to get this to work.

Current with Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
Text:&nbsp;
<input class="form-control" maxlength="12" style="width:130px;display:inline-block;" type="text" value="0.00">
</div>
</div>
```

Changing the above HTML to Bootstrap 5, I currently have the following that does not work:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 d-flex float-end">
Text:&nbsp;
<input class="form-control" maxlength="12" style="width:130px;" type="text" value="0.00">
</div>
</div>
```

Code in jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/korazy8s/o2wyz64u/36/

Comment: What happens when you enter the word 'align' into the search box at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2? This question has also been answered _here_ many times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 5 Input Text-Align right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257262/bootstrap-5-input-text-align-right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it, you could use margin-left auto on the children of col, or you could just use flexbox justify-content end(right).

Following an exmple where I replace your `float-end` with `justify-content-end`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container pt-3 m-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">NOT_IMPORTANT</div>

    <!-- I want the contents in this column to be:
     right aligned and single line
-->
    <div class="col-9 border p-1 justify-content-end d-flex">
      <span class="pt-1 pb-1 me-2">Name:</span>
      <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 200px;">
        <span class="input-group-text pt-1 pb-1">$</span>
        <input class="form-control pt-1 pb-1" maxlength="12" value="0.00">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex text-right">
      Text:&nbsp;
      <input class="form-control" maxlength="12" style="width:130px;" type="text" value="0.00">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```